# Trouble setting expirationTime on Google Drive permissions

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I've been using the Google API documentation to set and then update Google Drive permissions in the format below:

```js
const permissionObj = {
  expirationTime: '2017-04-10T17:04:30-04:00'
};

drive.permissions.update({
  auth: jwtClient,
  permissionId: resp.id,
  fileId: fileId,
  resource: permissionObj
}, (err, resp) => {

});
```

With this format I am able to update the role if included in the permissionObj, but when I pass in a new Date object or a string date like the one provided in my code above No expiration is set and I receive no errors.

Any idea what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you use a future time? What validations have you tried to see if it expired or not?

Comment: @noogui I did use a future time. I was checking expirations by listing the permissions and seeing it still existed. I was also able to access the drive file still by using the account I was testing on. Once I deleted the permission  using drive.permissions.delete() I was no longer able to access the file, but this method did not seem to add any expirationTime.

Comment: If you think you did everything right, you can open an issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).